# Unimodal sequence with zero sum

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove a Lemma which states that

If $a_{0}\leq a_{1}\leq a_{2}\dots\leq a_{k}\geq a_{k+1}\geq \dots \geq a_{n}$ is a unimodal sequence with nonnegative real numbers and the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}a_{i}=0$, then we have $\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i}\geq 0$ for even number $j$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i}\leq 0$ for odd number $j$

Can someone give me help on this? I tried to prove this by induction but failed since I didn't know how to use the condition that their sum is $0$

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a few cases:

**Case 1:** $j\leq k$ and $j$ is even.
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i} = a_{0}+(a_{2}-a_{1})+\dots+(a_{j}-a_{j-1})\geq 0$$

**Case 2:** $j\leq k$ and $j$ is odd.
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i} = -((a_{1}-a_{0})+(a_{3}-a_{2})+\dots(a_{j}-a_{j-1}))\leq 0$$

**Case 3:** $j > k$ and $j$ is even.
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i} = \begin{cases}(a_{j+1}-a_{j+2})+\dots+(a_{n-1}-a_{n})\geq 0, & n\text{ is even}\\
(a_{j+1}-a_{j+2})+\dots+a_{n}\geq 0, & n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

**Case 4:** $j > k$ and $j$ is odd.
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{j}(-1)^{i}a_{i} = \begin{cases}-((a_{j+1}-a_{j+2})+\dots+a_{n})\leq 0, & n\text{ is even}\\
-((a_{j+1}-a_{j+2})+\dots+(a_{n-1}-a_{n}))\leq 0, & n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$